# programmatically resize / reposition vaadin window

Tags: vaadin7

We have a Vaadin 7 application which can have several Vaadin window objects. To aid the user in managing these windows, I want to have a button which will resize/reposition the windows such as tile the windows. The code I have goes something like this:

```
for (Window window : ui.getWindows()) {
    window.setHeight(...);
    window.setWidth(...);
    window.setPositionX(...);
    window.setPositionY(....);
}
```

1. The window is added to the UI, user interacts with it, presses the button which runs the above pseudo code, and the window responds. (good).
2. If the user now moves/resizes the windows again, the same button has no effect. (bad)

Any idea why the resizing/repositioning does not continue to work in case 2 above?

I created a test program to clarify my issue:

```
package com.example.tilewindow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("tilewindow")
public class TilewindowUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TilewindowUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
static int counter = 1;


@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
    addWindow(createWindow(0, 0, 300, 300));
    addWindow(createWindow(500, 0, 300, 300));
    addWindow(createWindow(0, 500, 300, 300));

    Button newWindowButton = new Button("New Window 2");
    newWindowButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            addWindow(createWindow(0, 0, 500, 500));
        }
    });
    Button tileWindowsButton = new Button("Tile");
    tileWindowsButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Collection<Window> temp = getWindows();
            Collection<Window> windows = new ArrayList<Window>(temp);
            System.out.println("windows count = " + windows.size());
            int offset = 20;
            for (Window window : windows) {
                window.setHeight(200, Unit.PIXELS);
                window.setWidth(200, Unit.PIXELS);
                window.setPositionX(offset);
                window.setPositionY(offset);
                offset += 20;
                window.markAsDirty();
                System.out.println("   Found window, offset = ." + offset);
            }
            windows.clear();
            markAsDirty();
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(newWindowButton);
    layout.addComponent(tileWindowsButton);
}
private Window createWindow(int xIn, int yIn, int heightIn, int widthIn) {
    Window returnValue = new Window();
    returnValue.setPositionX(xIn);
    returnValue.setPositionY(yIn);
    returnValue.setHeight(heightIn, Unit.PIXELS);
    returnValue.setWidth(widthIn, Unit.PIXELS);
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    verticalLayout.addComponent(new Label("Window #" + counter++));
    verticalLayout.addComponent(new TextField());
    returnValue.setContent(verticalLayout);
    return (returnValue);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vaadin has acknowledged this as a bug. Will fix in a future release.

http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12885